# What does "next" under if-statement do?

Tags: python-3.6

I'm trying to create a schedule with regular expressions and given this piece of code, I don't understand the functionality of "next" here and how it could be compared to "continue", "pass" or "break", etc.

```
for j, line in enumerate(lines):
    m = reg_expr_w.match(line)
    if (m != None):
        week_variabel = m.group(4)
        next
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very odd thing to have. [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#next) is a function. So that line doesn't do anything. Could you be missing part of the code? Otherwise this is a mistake of some kind, either a bug or a remnant of some older piece of code that wasn't fully cleaned up. Where did you get it?

Comment: This is a school project and the code was written by the course instructor and it seems a trick to be discovered by students. However, I couldn't find any think about it when it comes to if-statement and that's why I'm asking here. The weird thing still when I run the code the Terminal doesn't complain about next existence under if-statement and run it normally.

Comment: @YamanDaif Yes it wont produce an error message. It is a perfectly valid statement that just doesn't do anything.  Like if you had a line that was just `1+1` it would run the code, but not assign it to anything so nothing really happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! @RedKnite